# Split String Based on Array in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, string, excel-formula, split

I have excel cells like the one below

`WYONG RD BRYANT DR TUGGERAH 2259 CENTRAL COAST (LGA) NSW`

I want to grab any sort of Road, Street, Drive, Highway etc. in one column and then the intersecting road in another column. SO for the above cell my desired output would be:

Column 1: WYONG RD

Column 2: Bryant DR

The code below brings the two roads into one column but I want to separate them but am having some difficulty on how to.

`=INDEX(IFERROR(LEFT(H2,SEARCH({" DR"," HWY"," ST"," CRK"," BND"," LN"," AV"," AVE"," MTWY"," RD"," CT"},H2)+3),""),MATCH(MAX(LEN(IFERROR(LEFT(H2,SEARCH({" DR"," HWY"," ST"," CRK"," BND"," LN"," AV"," AVE"," MTWY"," RD"," CT"},H2)+2),""))),LEN(IFERROR(LEFT(H2,SEARCH({" DR"," HWY"," ST"," CRK"," BND"," LN"," AV"," AVE"," MTWY"," RD"," CT"},H2)+2),"")),0)))`

Comment: Can you provide some more examples for variety?

Comment: ```WILLANDRA RD LILLIHINA AVE 200 CROMER 2099 NORTHERN BEACHES (LGA) NSW```
```BLAXLAND RD NR CNR ROSE ST CAMPBELLTOWN 2560 CAMPBELLTOWN (LGA) NSW```

Comment: I'd suggest this is a job for vba. Is that not an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check your formula but, unfortunately, it throws me an error. Thus, I spent some time and came up with the following solution:

Say, the input string is in the `A2` cell and the outputs are in the `B2` and `C2` cells. Thus, the formulas can be as follows:

For `B2`:

```
=LEFT(A2,
MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(" DR",  A2)+2,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" HWY", A2)+3,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" ST",  A2)+2,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" CRK", A2)+3,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" BND", A2)+3,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" LN",  A2)+2,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" AV",  A2)+2,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" AVE", A2)+3,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" MTWY",A2)+4,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" RD",  A2)+2,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" CT",  A2)+2,1000000)))
```

For `C2`:

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2&" ",""),
MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(" DR",  SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2&" ",""))+2,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" HWY", SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2&" ",""))+3,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" ST",  SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2&" ",""))+2,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" CRK", SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2&" ",""))+3,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" BND", SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2&" ",""))+3,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" LN",  SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2&" ",""))+2,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" AV",  SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2&" ",""))+2,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" AVE", SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2&" ",""))+3,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" MTWY",SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2&" ",""))+4,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" RD",  SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2&" ",""))+2,1000000),
    IFERROR(SEARCH(" CT",  SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2&" ",""))+2,1000000)))
```

Note that the second formula relies on the first formula output.